# Something goes wrong in this probability calculation

Tags: probability

Suppose we have random variables $X$ and $Y$ and it happens to be $Y=X$.

Now I have no idea of from where things goes wrong here:

$$
P(X)=\sum_{Y}P(X,Y)=\sum_{Y}P(X|Y)P(Y) = \sum_{Y}1 \cdot P(Y)=1
$$

But $X$ is an arbitrarily chosen random variable and it can't be always $P(X)=1$

Comment: It is not obvious what your question is. What does $P(X)$ mean too?

Comment: $P(X=x)$ $=\sum\limits_{y}P(X=x,Y=y)$ $=\sum\limits_{y}P(X=x\mid Y=y)P(Y=y) $ $= 1 \cdot P(Y=x)+0\cdot P(Y\not =x)$ $=P(Y=x)$ might be correct but unhelpful

Comment: Oops. I am so stupid. Right. $P(X)$ has no obvious meaning here. Thanks!